# Failed to run nextjs project

Tags: reactjs, next.js

```
error - ./node_modules/next/dist/client/dev/amp-dev.js
Module not found: Can't resolve 'C:\Users\User\Desktop\React Projektiudemy\app\next demo\first-next\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js' in 'C:\Users\User\Desktop\React Projekti\udemy\app\next demo\first-next\node_modules\next\dist\client\dev'
```

This is the error I get and i tried the answers on the stack. I tried babel downgrade and it didn't work. Can someone help me?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution to this problem. The answer is to remove "ud" from the file path. I made new folder and installed next js. The code shows no error.

I did this for anyone that has similar problem.